# How can I integrate Owasp ZAP with another third party application?

Tags: integration, implementation, owasp, zap

I'm developing an integration solution where Owasp Zap has to communicate with a third party application. Third party application then produces results in form of files that are stored on the server where it is installed. The web application and the third party application will not necessarily be on the same servers.
At the moment I am trying to search for the best methodologies and best practices that should be used to perform this integration. Since I am new to this area I do not know the exact terminologies that I should use to search for. I also do not know the exact term that describes such a setting where a web application is integrated with such a third party application.

I need some guidance about what kind of information to search for and what terminologies to use during the search. This is important for me because I also need to document to whole search process and the solution based on current methodologies and best practices.

Comment: TBH StackOverflow isnt the best place for questions like this (IMO). Try the ZAP User Group (or IRC channel), both of which are linked off https://www.zaproxy.org/community/

Comment: I can attempt to answer your questions here, but I'll just start off with a set of my own questions to find out more about your requirements, and the above options will make this process much quicker...

Comment: Okay, I got it! Thank you so much!